# Ambiguous template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a `Painter` template class with `paint()` template function. I am using tagging to specialize template function inside template class.
I have placed definition of template function `paint()` inside `Painter.h` and overloaded function inside `Painter.cpp`.

I get compiler error when I explicitly instantiate `paint()` in `Painter.cpp`. **My requirement is that I need the implementation of overloaded function `paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>)` in the file Painter.cpp.**

Source files are as follows:

**Painter.h**

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Color {
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2
};

template<Color>
struct ColorTag {

};

template<typename T>
class Painter {
public:

    template<Color MyColor>
    void paint(ColorTag<MyColor>);
    void paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>);

};

template<typename T>
template<Color MyColor>
void Painter<T>::paint(ColorTag<MyColor>){
    std::cout << "General" << std::endl;
}
```

**Painter.cpp**

```
#include "Painter.h"

template<typename T>
void Painter<T>::paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>){
    std::cout << "RED" << std::endl;
}

template void Painter<int>::paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>);
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Painter.h"

int main(){
    Painter<int> painter;
    painter.paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>());
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using

```
g++ Main.cpp Painter.cpp -std=c++11
```

I get following compiler error when I explicitly instantiate `paint()` in Painter.cpp

```
Painter.cpp:8:15: error: ambiguous template specialization ‘paint<>’ for ‘void Painter<int>::paint(ColorTag<(Color)0>)’
 template void Painter<int>::paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>);
               ^
Painter.cpp:4:6: note: candidates are: void Painter<T>::paint(ColorTag<(Color)0>) [with T = int]
 void Painter<T>::paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>){
      ^
In file included from Painter.cpp:1:0:
Painter.h:20:10: note:                 template<Color MyColor> void Painter<T>::paint(ColorTag<MyColor>) [with Color MyColor = MyColor; T = int]
     void paint(ColorTag<MyColor>);
```

**What I have tried**

**Firstly** I created a  template function called `instantiatePaint()` to call `paint()` function. Then I placed and instantiated it in `Painter.cpp` file. This worked. But this kind of feels awkward.

```
template<typename T>
template<Color MyColor>
void Painter<T>::instantiatePaint(ColorTag<MyColor>){
    paint(ColorTag<MyColor>());
}

template void Painter<int>::instantiatePaint(ColorTag<Color::RED>);
```

**Secondly** moved overloaded function definition from `Painter.cpp` to `Painter.h`. This works but breaks my requirement of having overloaded function `paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>)` in `Painter.cpp`.

Are there any better methods to fix the problem or what exactly is causing the ambiguity?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an explicit specialization with `T = int` so correct syntax is :

```
template<> 
void Painter<int>::paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>);
```

With this syntax, both g++ and clang compile the code. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c7df6023985604c)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you initialize whole class, instead of function?

```
template class Painter<int>;
```

Comment: This works until it breaks. There are case where we cannot instantiate entire template class explicitly. Lets say we have two structs that can replace `int`. `struct Box { static void foo(){ std::cout << "foo";} };`   `struct Cube { static void bar(){ std::cout << "Cube";} };`. Make template function `paint(ColorTag<MyColor>)` to call `T::bar()` and specialized function to call `T::foo()`. Now try to instantiate the full class using either `Box` or `Cube`.

Comment: Firstly note that in your code `paint(ColorTag<Color::RED>)` is not template specialization, it's `overloaded` function. Secondly, I don't know if I clearly understand what you want, anywat it's this what you meant: http://ideone.com/euoiPN

Comment: Yes template functions cannot be specialized inside template class. But what have done using tagging gives me the effect of pseudo template specialization. **My requirement is that I need the specialized (tagged) function in the Painter.cpp file itself.**. You can see **My attempts to fix** if you read towards the end of my question. As I have said in **my attempts to fix**, the problems is solved easily if I  just move pseudo specialized function to `Painter.h` without any _explicit instantiation_ in `Painter.cpp`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

enum Color {
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2
};

template<Color color = Color::RED>
struct ColorTag 
{
    // your Implementation
};

template<>
struct ColorTag <Color::RED>
{
    // your Implementation specific to Color::RED
};

template<typename T>
class Painter {
public:

    // template specialization can not apply on method level
    // use class or struct
    template<Color MyColor> 
    void paint(ColorTag<MyColor>);
};

template<typename T>
template<Color MyColor>
void Painter<T>::paint(ColorTag<MyColor> colorTag)
{
    std::cout << "General"<<std::endl;
}
```

working fine on visual Studio 2012 not sure about Gcc

Comment: please answer, you are very much sure that this will 100% work, "not sure" makes it dicey

Comment: because I have not checked it on GCC, I read somewhere double template is compiler dependent.